# Encrypt Mongo data in Meteorjs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, security, encryption, meteor

Is it possible to encrypt certain Mongodb field for particular collection when the document is being inserted? And then decrypt it while publishing the collection?

Comment: What's the use case? You may be better off encrypting the whole mongo data directory. eg. Using LUKS. MongoDB Security Docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/security-introduction/

Comment: I read the docs. But my database is in compose so i want to encrypt it so when i can't read the data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is overkill for your use case:

[Mylar](http://css.csail.mit.edu/mylar/) is a Meteor module which supports client-side encryption.

> Mylar stores only encrypted data on the server, and decrypts data only in users' browsers. [...] Mylar allows the server to perform keyword search over encrypted documents, even if the documents are encrypted with different keys. [...] Finally, Mylar ensures that client-side application code is authentic, even if the server is malicious. Results with a prototype of Mylar built on top of the Meteor framework are promising

You didn't ask for a framework, but homebred security is often done wrong.

Comment: Looks promising. Does it decrypt data in a Meteor publication?

Comment: @FardeemMunir: The data is decrypted automatically on client-side, you can write most of your application as you would without it.

Comment: Wow. That's sick. Not an over kill at all. Plus the developers are pretty good. Thanks for the absolutely brilliant solution.

Comment: I tried to make a demo but I don't really understand principal stuff. What do I have to add to like .insert() for it to encrypt it correctly.

Comment: @FardeemMunir: As far as I know principals should only be needed if you want to share data between different users. Did you have a look at their Chat example? git://g.csail.mit.edu/EncChat

Comment: Mylar is not under maintenance, Planifica:encryption is client side encryption only. Can you suggest a plugin which will be useful for the db side encryption.

Answer (score 5):

We have published a new package [planifica:encryption](https://github.com/Planifica/encryption) that let's you do client-side encryption of your mongo collections with ease! If follows the same principles as Mylar does (in fact it is based on the paper that Mylar is based on), but currently does not support all of Mylars features like server-side search.
On the other hand it uses far more advanced and performant encryption techniques for key generation and encryption that are more suitable for browsers. Also it does not replace or modify the meteor core, but instead is a normal package that uses hooks for all the automatic en-/decryption.
There is also a blog post to get you started [here](https://medium.com/@PhilippSpo/client-side-encryption-in-meteor-3ae982e557a8).

Comment: Just linking to your own library or tutorial is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code on how to do so and disclaiming that you wrote it makes for a better answer. See: **[What signifies “Good” self promotion?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212/200235)**

Comment: Was adding an explanation in the same moment you were making your comment ;)

Comment: Mylar is not under maintenance,   Planifica:encryption is client side encryption only. Can you suggest a plugin which will be useful for the db side encryption.