# How to secure data in Mongo DB of Meteor App

Tags: mongodb, encryption, meteor

I wish to encrypt/decrypt data of mongoDB using meteor App. Is there any package/module which supports encryption in Meteor for its database. I came across this package. [mylar](https://github.com/strikeout/mylar) and [oauth encryption](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/oauth-encryption) , is there any way to use these for MongoDB or any other method is available.Please guide , I am new to meteor. Thanks

I referred to this thread [Encrypt Mongo data in Meteorjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835411/encrypt-mongo-data-in-meteorjs) but was not able to resolve the issue. Adding it for reference.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this using the MeteorJs framework. My solution is not sexy but it works great.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/mariorodriguespt/b8c8a96ad2eccfb9b359

I simply encrypt the data before saving to the database using the collection-hooks package and when I'm publishing the data I simply decrypt it. I'm doing this only in the server so I don't send the encryption key to the client.

This is just an experiment from my personal Lab, for production it's a nightmare to maintain. Imagine yourself every time you want to read/write data...

Better solutions:

1. You can write a package that wraps find/update/delete to make your life a lot easier.
2. You can use a middleware to handle all the data encryption/decrypting. ( I don't know how to do this with Meteor but I think it's doable )

Real life:

I never got a project with this requirement. If someone exploits your web application and manages to dump all the data, the attacker gets the data decrypted. This could prevent an attacker from getting the database if he exploits directly the database server.

Working with an encrypted database is a nightmare by itself, it really easy to waste time on this. Also imagine some poor guy trying to optimise the database schema design.

I recommend you to develop your application without the encryption and when you're ready to launch simply add the encryption layer. Solution 1 would work great in my opinion. Don't forget to write migration guides, you'll need them :)

Answer (score 1):

Some of the key cryptography packages for Meteor include:

- jparker:crypto-aes
- jparker:crypto-sha256
- mrt:jsencrypt
- mrt:sjcl

All are available on [atmospherejs.com](http://atmospherejs.com)